# HC-05 bluetooth module as master, linking

Tags: terminal, bluetooth, arduino, avr, at-command

I want my HC-05 module to connect bluetooth keyboard as master.
So, after reading http://eskimon.fr/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/commandes_AT_HC05.pdf and few tutorials i've done something like this:

```
AT+ORGL
OK
AT+RMAAD
OK
AT+ROLE=1
OK
AT+INQM=0,3,48
OK
AT+CMODE=0 
OK //There i've tryed to AT+RESET device, but it makes no difference.
AT+INIT
OK
AT+INQ
+INQ:C473:1E:69A2C1,8043C,7FFF
+INQ:6C5D:63:4099E0,2540,7FFF //AT+RNAME of this device returns "bluetooth keyboard".
+INQ:1C7B:21:75618C,5A020C,7FFF
OK
AT+PAIR=6C5D,63,4099E0 //There I type "1234" and press enter on keyboard.
OK
AT+BIND=6C5D,63,4099E0
OK
AT+LINK=6C5D,63,4099E0
FAIL // There module starts re-inq devices.
```

Last command returns "FAIL" realy quckly, almoust with no delay, wich is strange, i guess. Ive tryed to press little button on keyboard, marked as "Connect" while linking, but it makes no difference. I've also tried to Link to the phone. It's successfully paired, but failed to link again.

EDIT:
I've unpaired my keyboard from phone, and HC-05 module begin to *think* a little, before return *FAIL*. Idk why it would make a difference. Any way, i become to think this is bluetooth versions issue. Keboard have v3.0 and HC-05 have 2.0+ version. But im sure all BT version must be back compat, are'nt they?

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else runs into same idea:
I found out, that HC-05 and similar modules implements *SPP* bluetooth profile, whereas keyboard using *HID* profile, wich is more secure and complicated. So, i guess this is impossible to do via HC-XX modules.